# water pressure regulator releasing a tiny bit of water

Tags: plumbing, leak, water-pressure, regulator

About a month ago i installed new water lines and a water pressure regulator.  The supply pressure is ~95psi and the regulator drops it to ~50psi before it continues to the house and workshop in 1.5" PVC.
The area around the valve and regulator look wetted, either a tiny leak on the fittings, or the regulator releases water during its operation.  Does anyone know if its normal for these water pressure regulators to release outboard a bit of water under normal operation?  I cant immediately find a leak source, but will continue to investigate if these things don't release water during operation.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally these are non reliving so no water leaks when the pressure changes, this may cause your pressure to shift a few psi on occasion but not more than a few psi.

I am wondering if you got a reliving type regulator.
These regulators release the over pressure ( normally caused by water heaters) the pressure is vented thus the leak. Most of the time a pressure tank is used to absorb the pressure created by the water heater and a non reliving regulator is used. If you purchased a reliving type you don’t need a pressure tank but it allows some water to be leaked out to maintain the pressure.

This is if the water is coming from the regulator from the looks it might be condensation.

Comment: I didnt even think of condensation....It was cold last night (36F) and the humidity was ~50%.

Comment: this one was "non-relieving" so i'm going with condensation but will keep an eye on it... thanks Ed!